# Linear system of 2 ODEs with respect to 2 functions. Stuck at solving.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The system is
\begin{align}
y'+x'&=\sin(t) \\
y+4x'+3x&=\cos(t).
\end{align}
Subtracting the equations (after multiplying the second one with the $\tfrac{d}{dt}$ operator, a lengthy proof suggests this is allowed) and scaling yields $2x''+x'=-\sin(t)$. Solving gives (also checked with Wolfram)
$$
x=C_1e^{-t/2}+C_2+\frac{1}{5}(\cos(t)+2\sin(t)).
$$
My textbook disagrees and says
\begin{align}
x&=C_1(-1+3e^{-t/2})-C_2(1-e^{-t/2})+\frac{1}{5}(\cos(t)+2\sin(t)) \\
y&=3C_1(1-e^{-t/2})+C_2(3-e^{-t/2})-\frac{2}{5}(3\cos(t)+\sin(t))
\end{align}
I have not even looked at $y$, since I am stuck at $x$. I have been using the same formula on other similar problems where my answers do match the textbook's.

Anyone can tell me what is going on here?

Comment: $C_1$ and $C_2$ are arbitrary, it seems that your solution is in line with the one presented in the textbook

Comment: I see. I just wonder how the author arrived at such a different outlay?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**: Rewrite your textbook solution for $x$, i.e.
$$x=-C_1+3C_1e^{-t/2}-C_2+C_2e^{-t/2}+\frac{1}{5}(\cos(t)+2\sin(t)).$$

Now, substitute $-C_1-C_2=c_2 \ $ and $\ 3C_1+C_2=c_1$. Hence, you will get your solution too.

Answer (score 0):

Hint.

From the first ODE

$$
x + y = -\cos t + C_0
$$

then we follow with

$$
(-x-\cos t+C_0)+4x'+3x =\cos t
$$

etc.